# How to share text and image using android share intent?

Tags: android, share-intent

I want to share Image and text using andoroid share intent. In Existing Code, It share "null.bin" file for whatsapp and for gmail "couldn't attach file" error.

```
String msg = title + "\n\nDownload the app now & Register using link:\n "+ invitationLink;

    Uri imageUri = (new Uri.Builder())
            .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
            .authority(getContext().getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.hblogo))
            .appendPath(getContext().getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.hblogo))
            .appendPath(getContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.hblogo))
            .build();


    //Share Android App Data To Other Apps
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    //Image Uri Share
    if(imageUri!=null){
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    }

    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
    sendIntent.setType("*/*");

    Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
    startActivity(shareIntent);

}
```

Comment: Please tell the value of `imageUri.toString()`. And we see no `null.bin` file.

Comment: I tried to replace  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri); with  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri.toString(); , but I am now getting "Sharing failed, Try again" error.

Comment: Very well. And im waiting for you to reply to my comment. It looks as if i asked for something.